# Elementor top container isn't editable and is not even in elementor navigation

Tags: wordpress, containers, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

While editing with Elementor I can't select the top part with an image and text over it. While every other section on the page is editable. How can I change the image and the text.

I can't get if that was ade through coding or what, or how can I edit it?
[Here the top heading ( media and entertainment law) and background image is not editable with elementor or any other way but every other thing is editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPabz.jpg)

Can you please guide what I can do about it?

I have tried elementor, custmize, edit page option. Don't know the cause.If it's with code where can I find and edit that?